# Image file name stored in a constant

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have a tableview with an image in each cell. I'm pulling the data for each cell from a plist including textlabel detailtextlabel and image file name. i am using

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_KEY];
```

the IMAGE_KEY constant to set the image. But it doesn't work. it DOES work if i just type the image file name in the message. I have double checked the file name that is stored in my plist and double checked the declaration inside of my constants file. Everything is spelled correctly. Is there a different way to use constants to set an image?

Comment: Edit your question to show us the definition of `IMAGE_KEY`.  Also include the name of the file where you define `IMAGE_KEY` and the name of the file where you try to use it.

Comment: I figured it out. I just realized I was storing the key name in my constant IMAGE_KEY so instead of using [UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_KEY]; I had to use [[self.dictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:IMAGE_KEY]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
 #define IMAGE_KEY "apple.jpg" // like this
```

Now:

```
 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@IMAGE_KEY];
```

if

```
 #define IMAGE_KEY @"apple.jpg" // like this
```

Now:

```
 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_KEY];
```

Answer (score 0):

check spelling mistakes, lower case upper case difference, Check for extension its spelling and case... put the code where you have defined your constant `IMAGE_KEY`

Answer (score 0):

how do you declare  IMAGE_KEY as constant? it must be string format.

```
#define Image_Key @"apple.jpg"
```

Please check what you are getting runtime in  IMAGE_KEY.

Comment: I prefix # but it makes bold plz tell me how do u prefix #

Comment: I checked by writing the IMAGE_KEY constant to the detailtextlabel of the cell and it shows the image name and extension

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
[[self.dictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:IMAGE_KEY]];
```